# Compile Error Next without For

Tags: vba, excel

This code combines all the columns in Sheet1(Orders) to into one column in Sheet3(Masterlist).

The issue that I am running into is on Line 26 an error Next without For.

Some post suggest that I have a loop inside a loop others say I need an End IF somewhere. I am new and will likely need to see what the revised code would look like. Comments don't seem to help me.

```
Sub ToArrayAndBack()
Dim arr As Variant, lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant, lIndex As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

ReDim arr2(Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells.Count - Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)

arr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value

Set myRange = Worksheets("Orders").Range("A1:A" & _
Worksheets("Orders").Cells(Worksheets("Orders").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 2
Do While i <= myRange.Rows.Count
     For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
         For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
                arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
                lIndex = lIndex + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
  i = i + i
Loop

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "MasterList" Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found Then
    Sheets.Add.Name = "MasterList"
End If

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList")
With ws
     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
     .Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
     .Rows(1).Delete
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are nesting For Loops you should always reference the variable to be incremented/decrementeed/stepped in the Next Statement

```
 For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
     For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
            arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
            lIndex = lIndex + 1
        End If
    Next lLoop2
Next lLoop1
```

Comment: That is exactly the answer I was going to share but was beat.

Comment: Well, it may be best practice, but not doing so shouldn't result in the error the OP is getting.

Comment: I made your changes . I am now getting Subscript out of range on line `arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)`. I am told that it could be because my variable was not declared. I am not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

I copied and pasted your code into a VBA **Sub** (for EXCEL 2010), and it compiles without any error. You are somehow not copying all of your code.

An error that I have encountered in the past is that an unprintable character occurs in the text, and produces spurious compile failures until it is located and removed. I suggest copying the code block from this question back into your source file, to remove the unprintable character.

Answer (score -1):

The code compiles for me which leads me to believe it could be a dead reference. In the VBE Click on Tools / References and see if there is something listed as "Missing"

Comment: I copied and pasted it back and now I am getting a Subscript out of Range on Line 24. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Your code compiles just fine. Try the following:

Uncheck Visual Basic For Application from VBA references save and add it back in.

Here is the steps if you don't know how to do this:

1. Go to the VBA editor,
2. Click on Tools then References
3. You should have an item called "Visual Basic For Application" uncheck that item
4. Click ok
5. Save your spreadsheet
6. Do step 1, and 2 above
7. Check the item you unchecked "Visual Basic For Application"
8. Click ok
9. Save your spreadsheet
10. Close your spreadsheet and any Excel instances and objects you may have as follow:
     -Close all Excel files and excel program if you have any open
     -Go to the Task Manager (by doing Alt+Ctrl+Del) then select Task Manager
     -Go to processes tab
     -Sort by process name
     -Look for any Excel.exe in the list and force close them all
11. Open your spreadsheet in question and try your code.

let us know.

Thank you!